# configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I am trying to compile an application called "iPerf" in my windows environment using cygwin.

When I try to do ./configure with my iPerf installation it throws following error:

```
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

I am not sure what it is trying to say with it but online search did not help much if you want to replicate what I am doing then here is the link of iPerf source which I am trying to compile in my cygwin environment :

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the iperf2 code base, you might want to try the [iperf3 code base](http://code.google.com/p/iperf/).

As another alternative to trying to compile this yourself, there's the [iperf-cygwin](http://code.google.com/p/iperf-cygwin/) project, which is a project to compile Iperf 2.x on Windows using Cygwin.

Comment: so using iperf cygwin worked.but it was missing congigure.Guess file so I had to manually add it from :http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/build-aux/ci/master/tree/config.guess